# Overlay of two functions leaves gaps

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a function defined as:

$\rho_{m}\left(\epsilon,m\right)=\left[-2\epsilon r\pm\left(4\epsilon^{2}r^{2}+m\lambda r^{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}$

I want to plot it for some $m\in \mathbb{Z}$, so I wrote this code:

```
Clear[r,\[Lambda]];
\[Lambda]=685*10^-9;
r=25*10^-3;
\[Rho]1[\[Epsilon]_,m_]=(-2*\[Epsilon]*r+(4*\[Epsilon]^2*r^2+m*\[Lambda]*r^3)^(1/2))^(1/2);
\[Rho]2[\[Epsilon]_,m_]=(-2*\[Epsilon]*r-(4*\[Epsilon]^2*r^2+m*\[Lambda]*r^3)^(1/2))^(1/2);
M=Range[-5,5,1];
p1=Show[Plot[\[Rho]1[\[Epsilon]*10^-3,#]*10^3, {\[Epsilon],-0.5,0.5}, PlotRange -> {{-0.5,0.5},{0, 5}},AxesOrigin->{-0.5,0},PlotTheme->"Monochrome"] & /@ M];
p2=Show[Plot[\[Rho]2[\[Epsilon]*10^-3,#]*10^3, {\[Epsilon],-0.5,0.5}, PlotRange -> {{-0.5,0.5},{0, 5}},AxesOrigin->{-0.5,0},PlotTheme->"Monochrome"] & /@ M];
Show[{p1,p2}]
```

Which outputs:

[image]

However, there are some tiny gaps where the two functiosn meet, but I was expecting them to be continuous. How can I fix that?

Comment: Adding the option PlotPoints->1000 to both your Plots will make those gaps much less visible.

Comment: I think that the problem may be that the functions become imaginary at $\epsilon = 0$. `Plot` doesn't plot anything at all when the value is imaginary. When it happens precisely at the point where they're supposed to meet I guess it becomes a numerical issue, hence why `PlotPoints` may help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you turn the equation around and plot $\epsilon$ as a function of $\rho$, then there are no gaps and no branches:

```
λ = 685*10^-9;
r = 25*10^-3;
ParametricPlot[Table[10^3 {(m r^3 λ - ρ^4)/(4 r ρ^2), ρ}, {m, -5, 5}],
  {ρ, 0, 5*10^-3}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]